# Modifying renderings programatically - can update the Shared Layout and Final Layout together but can't seem to only update the Final Layout?

Tags: presentation, rendering-parameters, experience-editor

I'm working on a script to modify rendering parameters. I noticed that I seem to only be able to modify the Shared Layout and not the Final Layout. I can retrieve the Final Layout field and work based off of it, but in order to apply the changes, `item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();` works but `item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();`

I am concerned about modifying the Shared Layout having unintended consequences from modifying the shared layout instead of the Final Layout, as language versions may have different renderings and I don't want to overwrite language-specific renderings.

This updates my layout (both Shared and Final):

```
var layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]);
var layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
var deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(defaultDeviceId);

<stuff to modify the renderings>

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

This does not appear to update anything:

```
var layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]);
var layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
var deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(defaultDeviceId);

<stuff to modify the renderings>

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

EDIT: I am not just trying to modify rendering parameter field values but also need to be able to move a rendering's position and to change its placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://cristinadragos.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/sitecore-8-changing-renderings-programmatically/) blogpost, you can do it in the following way:

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
```

Comment: That seems to work! Not sure why `item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();` didn't

Answer (score 0):

If you Sitecore version is 8 or later then you Probably need to use SetFieldValue([NotNull] Field field, [NotNull] string value) method to change __Renderings or __Final Renderings.

Something like below,

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
LayoutField.SetFieldValue(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField], "Updated Value");
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Refer Sitecore Document [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-versioned-layout-api-changes.html) also note this particular comment from Sitecore document mentioned in the link,

> The **SetFieldValue** method does not always save the complete layout value to the
>   field. If possible, it saves only the XML patch to the selected field.

Comment: It appears this would only work for setting rendering parameter field values and not for changing the placeholder or the position in the layout